# how to combine awk and sed command together

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have two commands ,

```
awk 'NR%2{printf $0 "      ";next}1' FileName
```

and

```
sed '1d;' FileName .
```

I want these two command to be used together as a single command . I tried using | format , it is not working

**sample IO**

Input:

```
header
1
2
3
4
5
```

output:

```
1   2
3   4
5
```

Comment: What `exactly` have you tried? What happened? What did you hope for? Please give proper examples of expected input and output. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have multiple columns . I have to merge them together by ignoring header and footer in a text file . If I use these commands separately it is working . Bu I need this as a single script

Comment: You never need sed when you are using awk and never do `printf $0` or you will get a nasty surprise when `$0` contains formatting chars (e.g. `%s`). Post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: I have multiple columns separated by spaces in a text file . I need the second line should be joined with first line likewise forth line with third line sequentially

Comment: Include your sample input file and expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '1d;N;s/\n/   /'
```

the same in 1 sed.

- `1d`: delete line if it is the 1st of the input (header for you). Sed loop after a d, so next instruction are ignored and next line is treated in a new run.
- `N`: load a new line (so 2 line with a `\n` between them in current buffer)
- `s\n/   /`: replace new line by several space
- print result of this loop
- restart the process until end of file with next line.

Comment: . Your command is working fine . Can you explain me the command

Comment: Thank you sir .... Can you help me to convert the cose into shell script

Comment: I have a header and footer . It delets the header . The operation should not be perfomed for header .

Comment: added a sample of IO in post

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
awk 'NR != 1 && !(NR % 2) {printf $0 "      "; next} 1' FileName | tail +2
```

Comment: If I use this , the output is different ...... My secons column is also erased

Comment: You'll need to show sample input and desired output.

Comment: I should not delete the header . I need to display header and the AWK operetions should be perfomed only to the body

Comment: @JimMacaulay: OK, I edited my answer to do work the way you show in your edited question.

Comment: Point is to remove the `header` from the output. You did also change OPs post to include the `header` that should not be there in the output.

Comment: @Jotne: OK, I removed the header.

Answer (score 0):

Why not all in one command? This should do both our request with `awk`

```
awk 'NR>1 && ORS=NR%2==0?"      ":RS' file
1      2
3      4
5
```

Comment: If I use this AWK Command the olumns are not aligned properly . Hoe wto arrange it

Comment: @JimMacaulay Try: `awk 'NR>2 && ORS=NR%2?"\t\t":RS' file`.  It will use `tab` not `space`

Comment: @JimMacaulay Updated my post to skip first line and get it into correct column.  You can still change space to tab.